# How to upload a JPEG to a server via HTTP POST from an ESP32 with IDF?

Tags: python, php, c, http, esp32

I'm using an ESP32 with IDF 4.4 and want to use a HTTP POST to upload a JPEG, that is currently stored in a byte array (read from a camera). I already set up a server with an upload script in PHP. The script should simply receive the JPEG and store it somewhere on the server.
Source code of everything is below to make this more readable.

I already tested the server by writing a python script that posts a JPEG to the server from a different PC. With this configuration the JPEG gets uploaded to the server correctly.

Now I'm trying to upload a JPEG with an ESP32, but I can't get it to work. I'm also struggling to find examples for uploading JPEG on ESP32 httpd client. I simply don't know how to do it.

The ESP32 is already connected to a wifi network, i will not show the code for that as it works.

There are no errors while executing the ESP32 code, it seems like everything went fine.
I'm currently analyzing the POST by writing the superglobals `$_POST` and `$_FILES` to a file.
When I'm uploading with the python script, i can see the JPEG in `$_FILES` (see `log_py.txt`). With the ESP32 both superglobals are empty (see `log_esp.txt`).

Is there any way to debug what the server is receiving exactly except for the content of the superglobals?

Also I'm a bit confused where to "insert" the key, that's called `image` in the python and php script to access the "correct" file, in the ESP32 POST.

Does anyone have suggestions on where to start debugging?

Thanks you in advance!

**Python script:**

```
import requests

url = "http://X.X.X.X/upload.php"
image_path = "pic.jpg"
file = {"image": open(image_path, "rb")}

response = requests.post(url, files=file)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("POST request successful")
else:
    print("POST request failed: ", response.status_code)

print(response.text)
```

**PHP upload:**

```
<?php

$path = "picpath/";

$log = 'log.txt';
$logfile = fopen($log, 'w');
$text = var_export($_FILES, true) . "\r\n\r\n" . var_export($_POST, true);
fwrite($logfile, $text);
fclose($logfile);


if(isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $temp_dir = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    $dir = $path . $filename;
    
    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_dir, $dir)) {
        echo "saved image";
    } else {
        echo "cannot save image";
    }
} else {
    echo "cannot upload image";
}
?>
```

**ESP32:**

```
#define _SERVER_URL    "http://X.X.X.X/upload.php"

esp_http_client_config_t _server_config = {
    .url = _SERVER_URL,
    .method = HTTP_METHOD_POST,
    .event_handler = _server_httpEventHandler
};

esp_http_client_handle_t _server_client = NULL;

void server_sendJpeg(uint8_t* jpeg, uint32_t jpegSize)
{
    char jpegSizeStr[7] = "";
    snprintf(jpegSizeStr, sizeof(jpegSizeStr), "%d", jpegSize);

    _server_client = esp_http_client_init(&_server_config);
    esp_http_client_set_method(_server_client, HTTP_METHOD_POST);
    esp_http_client_set_header(_server_client, "Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
    esp_http_client_set_header(_server_client, "Content-Length", (const char*) jpegSizeStr);
    esp_http_client_set_post_field(_server_client, (const char*) jpeg, jpegSize);
    
    esp_http_client_perform(_server_client);
}
```

**log_py.txt:**

```
array (
  'file' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'pic.jpg',
    'full_path' => 'pic.jpg',
    'type' => '',
    'tmp_name' => 'C:\\SOMEPATH\\phpB8E7.tmp',
    'error' => 0,
    'size' => 5163,
  ),
)

array (
)
```

**log_esp.txt:**

```
array (
)

array (
)
```

Comment: Using Wireshark you can look at the packets transmitted and received by your ESP32. You can either set it up on the server if you have root access and monitor the traffic coming from the ESP32 IP, or use a computer as an access-point and monitor the traffic here.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Thanks to @Elzaidir i looked at both POSTs in Wireshark.

The Python POST had `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` and the ESP32 POST had `Content-Type: image/jpeg`. That was the problem.

`multipart/form-data` posts to `$_FILES` with some additional information other than the raw JPEG data. It's also possible to post more than one file at once with this method.

`image/jpeg` does neither post to `$_FILES` nor `$_POST` and only one image.

Here is the **PHP upload** to receive and store the JPEG with the existing ESP32 code:

```
<?php

$path = "picpath/pic.jpg";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] === 'image/jpeg') {
  $pic = file_get_contents('php://input');

  if (file_put_contents($path, $pic) !== false) {
    echo "upload successful";
  } else {
    echo "cannot save image";
  }
} else {
  echo "cannot upload image";
}
?>
```